# Настройка bind на любой домен у которого наши NS-сервера

Tags: dns, домен, bind, ns

Возможно ли настроить bind, что бы он обрабатывал любой домен у которого указаны наши NS сервера? Что бы не приходилось добавлять зону для каждого домена.

Клиенты регистрируют через нас домены 2го уровня. Домены привязываются к нашему DNS серверу. Для каждого домена создается своя зона в конфиге. А вот файл таблицы зоны единый для всех зон. Назрел вопрос, можно ли упростить схему, что бы каждому новому домену указывать только наши NS сервера. И наш DNS будет обрабатывать любой домен. На доменах клиентов находятся рекламные страницы, поэтому допускается неверифицированное использование наших NS серверов.

Перефразирую: Можно ли создать зону по умолчанию? Пример:

```
zone "*" {type master; file "default.db";};
```

Comment: Поясните плиз вот это: _Для каждого домена создается своя зона в конфиге. А вот файл таблицы зоны единый для всех зон._ Если я правильно понял, то у меня возникает вопрос про SOA записи каждой зоны. И что означает "неверифицированное использование"? Это - *не авторитативные* NS-ы?

Comment: прошу уточнить, SOA записи зоны что именно? на описание неверифицированного использования можно не обращать внимания, это не технический момент.

Comment: SOA записи выходят одинаковые для всех зон: @ IN SOA ns1.dns_domain.com. noc.dns_domain.com. (...)

Comment: Мой вопрос больше касался следующего: вы хотите создавать в named.conf записи разных зон `zone "any_domain" {type master; file "any_domain.db";};`, `zone "any_domain_1" {type master; file "any_domain.db";};` направленных на один файл any_domain.db ?

Comment: Если данный named более ни для чего не используется попробуйте сделать свою зону `.` в которой указать `*. IN A ...`. не знаю правда чем это закончиться и заработают ли при этом домены более чем первого уровня

Comment: @Mike свою рутовую зону? Да вы, батенька, Корепфильд! ))

Comment: @AlexanderPushkarev Ну другого решения боюсь не предвидится, так что остаются крайние меры :) ТС же хочет вообще не перечислять никакие зоны и заставить свою DNS отвечать на любые запросы нужным ip

Comment: @Mike из данных задачи я пока не вижу решения. Если бы они управляли зоной первого уровня `.xyz`, то да, это было бы естественно. А так пока не найн.

Comment: @Mike для нашего сценария было бы логично иметь возможность просто настроить зону по умолчанию. но умеет ли это DNS сервер? может не bind, может другой? ведь когда приходит запрос по домену bind открывается свой named.conf и просто ищет зону домена, и например, если нет, то может использовать зону по умолчанию, если есть: zone "*" {..}

Comment: @AlexanderPushkarev мой вопрос именно в том - можно ли настроить единую зону по умолчанию для любого домена который резолвится на наши NS сервера? как раз что бы не создавать zone "any_domain_1". при этом "any_domain.db" уж не изменяется, используется единый для всех зон. вообще не вносить изменения в конфиги bind. только у домена указать наши NS сервера. потому что на сервере все домены обрабатываются одним и тем же приложением.

Comment: @psaproxy В bind нет такой возможности. Поэтому я и предложил попробовать описать корневую зону, и в ней описать `*` которая в описании зоны означает любой субдомен. вопрос лишь в том, справится ли она с двумя уровнями субдоменов. По идее это вполне может прокатить. Есть ли в других DNS не знаю, берите документацию каждого из них и изучайте. Вообще фича явно не стандартная. Видел я какой то довольно гибкий DNS, только он падал постоянно